# How do I create a function to logout a User when logged in as an Admin using Python with Redis

Tags: python, redis

Logged in as an Administrator, I want to be able to logout a logged-in user.  I am using Python and Redis.

I have created a function to be call in the view/controller but I am getting the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'redis'

function:

```
 def logout_logged_in_user(self, session):
        """Logout logged in user."""
        self.redis.delete(RedisSessionInterface.prefix + session.sid)
```

View/Controller:

```
def logout_loggedin_user(user_id):
    """Define the logout action for logged in user."""
    redis = RedisInterface.connection(RedisDatabases.CLIENT_SESSION)
    user_session = redis.get(str(user_id))
    try:
        RedisSessionInterface.logout_logged_in_user(user_session, session)
    except ValueError:
        pass  # create an alert cannot logout self
    return redirect('/accounts/logged_in_users_dashboard.html')
```